# $(this).find works in IE but not in Chrome/FF

Tags: jquery

This site is using jQuery 1.8.2

The following code works in IE 11, but does not work in Chrome/FF:

```
    existingProduct = $(this).find(".csConditionCell").html();
    console.log('existingProduct : ' + existingProduct);
```

existingProduct just prints out a blank in Chrome/FF.  In IE it returns `testValue`

```
function postRatingControlTest(newCondition, rating, product) {

    var conditionFound = false;
    var rowCount = document.getElementById("hdnRowCount").value;
    var countryId = document.getElementById("hdnCountryId").value;
    rating = getRatingTranslation(countryId, rating);

    getHiddenRatings();

    var existingProduct;
    var existingRating;

    $('.csGridTable tr').each(function () {
        existingProduct = $(this).find(".csConditionCell").html();
        console.log('existingProduct : ' + existingProduct);

        if (existingProduct == newCondition) {
            existingRating = $(this).find(".csRatingCell").html();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I change existingProduct to this:

```
existingProduct = $(this).html();
console.log('existingProduct : ' + existingProduct);
```

**The following is returned:**

```
existingProduct : <td><input id="row0_condition" readonly="" class="csConditionCell" value="testValue"></td><td class="csAdjustmentCell"><input type="button" value="-" class="Actionbuttonstyle" style="width:20px;" onclick="adjustRating('-','0');"></td><td class="csAdjustmentCell"><input type="button" value="+" class="Actionbuttonstyle" style="width:20px;" onclick="adjustRating('+','0');"></td><td><input id="row0_rating" readonly="" class="csRatingCell" value="+0"></td><td><input id="row0_product" readonly="" class="csProductCell" value="Life"></td><td class="csDeleteCell"><input type="button" value="X" class="Actionbuttonstyle" style="width:20px;" onclick="deleteRatingRow(0);"></td>
```

Is there any information as to why the .find method only works in IE?  Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: @connexo - it is built dynamically.  The section where it says the following is returned is 1 full row in the table.  There could be multiple rows in this table.

Comment: So how do you know these elements exist and are DOM ready at the time your $.each executes?

Comment: Remember to pick an answer so others immediately see your problem was solved.

Comment: @connexo - yep I was waiting for the cool down period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input.csConditionCell` is an input element and as such, does not have `content` or `innerHTML`. You want to use `$(this).find(".csConditionCell").val()`

Same is true for your 2nd `find()` attempt. If this works in IE11 it only proves how buggy that wanna-be-"browser" is.

Comment: It should be noted that the fact that it works in IE is not a quality for praise but probably an indication of microsoft's failure... lol then you updated to say just that. good one

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Yeah it is a corporate standard that we use it.